# TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' al ejecutar un programa en Python

Tags: numpy, python-3.7, tensorflow

Tengo el siguiente programa en python:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import wave
import os

# Nombre de la carpeta donde se encuentran los archivos de audio
AUDIO_FOLDER = "audios"

# Diccionario de correspondencias entre las etiquetas y los enteros
labels_dict = {
    "hombre_adulto": 0,
    "mujer_adulta": 1,
}

# Cargar los archivos de audio y sus etiquetas en una lista
audio_files = []
labels = []
for file in os.listdir(AUDIO_FOLDER):
    # Separar la etiqueta y el nombre del archivo de audio
    label, _ = file.split("_")
    # Convertir la etiqueta a un formato de enteros
    label = labels_dict[label]
    # Cargar el archivo de audio en un array de numpy
    audio = wave.open(f"{AUDIO_FOLDER}/{file}", "rb")
    audio_array = np.frombuffer(audio.readframes(-1), dtype=np.int16)
    audio_files.append(audio_array)
    # Añadir la etiqueta a la lista de etiquetas
    labels.append(label)
    audio.close()

# Convertir las etiquetas a un formato compatible con el modelo de red neuronal
labels = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(labels)

# Crear un modelo de red neuronal
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, input_shape=(audio_files[0].shape[0],)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(set(labels)), activation="softmax"))

# Compilar el modelo de red neuronal
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])

# Entrenar el modelo de red neuronal con el conjunto de datos de entrenamiento
model.fit(audio_files, labels, epochs=10)

# Guardar el modelo de red neuronal entrenado en un archivo
model.save("mi_modelo.h5")

# Mostrar un resumen del modelo de red neuronal entrenado
model.summary()
```

Este programa busca en una carpeta una serie de archivos *.wav*. Sus nombres son:
0_0.wav
0_1.wav
0_2.wav
0_3.wav
0_4.wav
....
1_0.wav
1_1.wav
1_2.wav
1_3.wav
1_4.wav
...
siendo 1_x para voces de mujer adulta y 0_x para voces de hombre adulto.

Resulta que cuando lo ejecuto me dice lo siguiente:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\visualstudio\red_neuronal\detecta.py", line 24, in <module>
    label = labels_dict[label]
KeyError: '0'
```

No entiendo de qué se queja... ¿Alguna pista?

Edit:
al aplicar el consejo de CandidMoe me devuelve lo siguiente:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\visualstudio\red_neuronal\entrena.py", line 40, in <module> model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(set(labels)), activation="softmax")) TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

de donde sale el numpy.ndarray?

Comment: Tienes un archivo de nombre "1_4.wav". Con split("_") lo separas y en `label` queda "0". Luego tratas de acceder al diccionario con esa llave `labels_dict[label]`, pero la llave '0' no existe. ¿Qué intentas hacer?

Comment: quiero que 0 o 1 sea la etiqueta que le paso a tflow. cómo me queda 0 en label?

Comment: Te lo acabo de explicar. Creo que tienes una confusión respecto al uso de diccionarios.

Comment: cambio los nombres de archivo de 0_x a hombre_adulto_x y de 1_x a mujer_adulta_x y parece que avanza, ahora te digo mas

Comment: ahora dice:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\visualstudio\red_neuronal\entrena.py", line 40, in <module>
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(set(labels)), activation="softmax"))
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Comment: El formato del sitio es "pregunta - respuesta"; no es un foro. Lo mejor es que edites la pregunta para que refleje la situación actual.

Comment: gracias, aplico edit